# Add variable inside of a function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
var elements = parent.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function () {
   return confirm_exit('".$_SESSION['SES_abr_langue']."');
  }
}
```

And I need for the onclick to be appended to the existing onclick event, if it exists.

When I add `elements[i].onclick` inside the function() it just "hardcodes" it. Meaning it literally puts elements[i].onclick instead of the value of the onclick.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you actually want to do? What do you mean by "value of the onclick"?

Comment: some links have a hardcoded onclick event. With the above function it is replacing the hardcoded onclick event with the one in the function. I would need for both to fire.

Comment: use addEventListener as suggested below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using addEventListener:

```
function onLinkClick() {
    return confirm_exit('".$_SESSION['SES_abr_langue']."');
}
var elements = parent.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (elements[i].addEventListener) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", onLinkClick, false);
  } else if (elements[i].attachEvent)  {// for < IE9
      elements[i].attachEvent("onclick", onLinkClick);
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Use the following if you want to have control over the original onclick:

```
function createLinkEvent(orgOnClick) {
    return function(e) {
        if (!confirm_exit('".$_SESSION['SES_abr_langue']."')) {
            return false;
        }
        if (orgOnClick) {
            return orgOnClick(e);
        }
        return true;
    };
}


}
var elements = parent.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = createLinkEvent(elements[i].onclick);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I basically used this except put my function directly into the attachEvent function, instead of having a seperate one. Now I have another small issue. I assume this adds my function AFTER the original hardcoded onclick event? Is there a way to add it BEFORE the original? Reason: the original is a redirect so whether a user clicks OK or CANCEL they get redirected no matter what.

Comment: @cwal see my edit, it's untested code, but I think it'll work

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Much appreciated. However it seems to work perfectly the first time, but not everytime thereafter. Not fishing for you to edit again, I will debug and try to work it out myself, but if you had a general idea of what the problem might be it could set me in the right direction.

Comment: Not really sure, if you can't find the problem, you can try to reproduce it using http://www.jsfiddle.net and post the link